# Error while trying to run Whatsapp on Chrome with the Archon Runtime : import extension is not installed. can't load manifest file

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons

I would like to run **Whatsapp** on **Chrome** using this extension [Archon Runtime](https://archon-runtime.github.io/). To achieve the goal,this is what I did :

- 1) I've got the **apk file** of Whatsapp

  2) I've installed **Chrome OS** and the extension named [twerk](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/twerk/mdiapfgnkdaaphalggbdnklnlkkodnei).

  3) I've given the apk file to twerk and it has created the proper
  Archon files for running whatsapp on Chrome for Windows

  4) Unfortunately it didn't work because this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiOh1.png).

What can I do to fix that error ?

Comment: Why not just run [WhatsChrome - Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatschrome/bgkodfmeijboinjdegggmkbkjfiagaan?hl=en) or the official MacOS or Windows WhatsApp [Download WhatsApp](https://www.whatsapp.com/download/?_fb_noscript=1)?

Comment: there is a reason : the whatsapp versions that you are talking about create a link between the PC and the phone and they make the battery discharge quickly. Actually I'm using whatsapp with Bluestack and I have fixed this problem,BUT this tool is too heavy. So,I've thought that if I can install whatsapp with the Archon RunTime I can have a lighter virtual machine where i can run whatsapp.

Comment: Consider explaining the error in more detail within your question so that potential answerers can more easily assist you.

Comment: there are no further explanations,since I'm not a programmer.